# How to link search bar with your own code repository using an API IntelliJ idea?

Tags: api, intellij-idea, repository, searchbar

I have my repository (suppose code.example.com) and an API to get access to it. I want IntelliJ search bar (ctrl+shift+F) to perform a search for files/projects in the given specified repository also. How can I do this?

I am not able to find the correct way.

Please help me.

Comment: So, once you checkout the repository, you want to find something in it using (ctrl+shift+F) - correct?  what's the issue that prevents you from doing this?

Comment: Like I have my own repository (code.example.com) and I am working on IntelliJ now suppose I search for some keyword in the search bar it will show the files present in IntelliJ projects. I want to show the results present in my repository also with one single search bar action. This is my point. I want to make a plugin for it.

Comment: I see... what have you tried so far?

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: I tried to learn the search algorithm used by IntelliJ but didn't get the way to the solution. I  encountered the Program Structure Interface(PSI) API in IntelliJ dealing with some sort of such things. But not able to get the way to the solution.

Comment: Ok, well - as is, your question does not meet the community guidelines.  You'd need to have more research done and tried something, then comeback with more specific blocking issues to get the necessary help.  Have you tried the IntelliJ plugin dev forums?